# Generate more images of an object at different angles

Tags: image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have several images of a rotating object. Each image shows a different angle. Now I want to let the user rotate the object with his or her fingers. This works but there aren't enough frames to show a smooth rotation. It's too jumpy.

I want to make it smoother and by that I probably need to generate more "steps", generate images of different missing angles. Is there an existing algorithm or technique I could use?

Comment: How many frames do you have? And what sort of images are you dealing with? Pictures or illustrations? Constant or different lighting?

Comment: Between 10 and 36 frames, but I want to use as less as possible. Pictures, photo shots of objects. Constant lighting.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you try to interpolate pixel values temporaly between two consecutive images it would result in poor results but it might worth the try.

A more interesting approach would be to make a 3d estimation of your object using stereoscopic technics and then to project a synthetic view of the estimated scene at an intermediary position. For this to work, you will need to now the precise angle of the object at each frame. Occlusion is also an issue with stereoscopy.

Comment: I think I'll try to interpolate the pixel values of two images. But it doesn't keep rotation in mind.

I do have the precise angle of each frame though, and I was hoping there was an existing technique in-between interpolating pixel values and 3d estimation.